# How to fix: "no tests found" when I have written tests?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am learning phpunit and I wrote a simple test but when I try to start it with console, it cant find it. I start up phpunit with: "./vendor/bin/phpunit"

This is the test. It is located in ./tests/

```
?php


require 'app/ball.php';

class testBalls extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public $ballInstance;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->ballInstance = new Ball();
    }

    public function testStealing(){
        $this->ballInstance->setBalls(100);

        $this->ballInstance->stealBall();

        $this->assertEquals(99,$this->ballInstance->getBalls());
    }
}
```

This is the tested php script. It is located in ./app/

```
<?php

class Ball{

    private $ballCount;


    public function getBalls(){
        return $this->ballCount;
    }

    public function setBalls($number){
        $this->ballCount = $number;
    }

    public function stealBall(){
        $this->ballCount = $this->getBalls()-1;
    }
}
```

And this is the phpunit config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Seems incomplete, is Ball setup in psr in composer.json? Also `suffix="Test.php"` will be looking for `testTest.php`, presuming *This is the test* means *This is the ./tests/test.php*

Comment: Heres an example [phpunit.xml](https://github.com/phppackage/magic-class/blob/master/phpunit.xml) from one of my crappy libs, which tends to always be the same values in phpunit.xml once setup, perhaps its of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class testBalls` should be `class BallTest`.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize that the name of class or file matters.